# mysql 5.5 strange bug

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a database in MySQL Server 5.5. The database is created, I know this as when I do

```
SHOW DATABASES;
```

It shows me my database in the list of all databases from the commandline.

But when i go inside

> C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\data\

my database is not visible there. In fact with

```
SHOW DATABASES;
```

it shows me 6 databases in the list but inside

> C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\data\

shows only two databases.

Its really strange error I m experiencing, the database is created but not actually created
feels like the commandline is cheating with me!

thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Are you running 32-bit MySQL on 64-bit Windows? Check "Program Files (x86)".

Answer (score 1):

Please check the `my.cnf` in the mysql installment folder.

like this:

```
datadir="C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.0/Data/"
```

it will show you the right folder.

Comment: Thanks Eric
Already checked it, it shows the same path
datadir="C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.0/Data/"
I noticed I have 3 different installations:
Microsoft SQL Server;
Xampp;
MySQL Server 5.5;
may be this has to do something with my bug, not sure

Comment: ugh, I want to make this a comment >.<

Comment: @jcolebrand Why can't you make it a comment (is it because it has an upvote) ???

Comment: Because it doesn't have an associated user on our site. Gray ghost name.